# In Javascript, process list synchronously

Tags: javascript, arrays, control-flow

I have a given collection of items to be processed; each item must wait for the completion of the previous one.

By collection of items I mean an array of integer values.

By "processing" I mean make a POST to a HTTP server, passing the integer value of each array element.

I've found something that looks like waht I'm looking for: [doSynchronousLoop.js](https://gist.github.com/steve-taylor/5075717) but I wonder if there are alternatives.

Comment: What kind of collections - How are you sending the collections - Who is processing the collections?

Comment: May the site pause rendering while processing? If yes, just do a "synchronus" ajax request

Comment: @TobSpr That's ridiculous what if the server "suddenly becomes faster"? Unless he's only using 2 collections then I guess it'd be alright

Comment: Post your processing code.

Comment: @Nate I mean something like `for (var i = 0;i<5;i++) {$.ajax({async:false, type: "POST", url: "", success: function(msg) {/* process data */}})} `

Comment: Does the server need to send a 'processed' command back to the client once it's completed the task so the client knows when to send the next batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your site may pause rendering while doing the requests, here's a solution with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
// process 5 items
for (var i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
   // ajax request done with jquery
   $.ajax({
      async: false, /* this makes it execute synchronously */
      url: "the url to handle item #i",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(msg) {
          // process data for item #i
      } 
   })
}
```

**Edit:** you can solve it asynchronously, too:

```
items = [put your items here]
current_item = 0

function processItem() {
    if (current_item == items.length) {
      // list processing finished
      return;
    }

    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      url: "the url to handle item #current_item",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(msg) {
          // process data for item #current_item
          processItem();
          current_item++;
      } 
   })

}
```

Don't miss to put the variables in a scope, I just left them in global scope to make the example easier to understand.

See also the docs: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: There's no need to make the AJAX requests synchronous (as they'll just be JAX requests). Use a callback function that pops the last element out of your array of elements and calls itself when it's done.